# Fibonaci() performing worse when multithreaded

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, asynchronous

Learning how well the threading works in Kotlin. Wrote a benchmarking class to try out different methods. In the scenario I take a method() and process it loopTimes.

For simple method, the threading is behaving close to what I would expect: When threads are used the timing is drastically cut by about factor of 6.

simple looped method that is called from multiple threads:

```
   for (i in 0 until 1000) {
       Math.pow(3.0, 3.0)
   }
```

However, while calling

```
   fibonacci(23)
```

The threaded runs perform drastically worse, by about factor of 5.

This was very unexpected. I am not locking anything within the `fibonacci` its just recursively calls itself, which I would expect to be happening completely independently on each thread. And hence, would expect threaded approaches to make `fibonacci` complete much faster. Then non threaded approaches. Why would fibonacci perform in such a way?

Here is the code of the class (go() is the invoking method)

```
package com.asgard.sandbox

import com.asgard.core.out.Out
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Runnable
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool
import java.util.concurrent.Future
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

class BenchmarkOfDifferentThreadingOptions(private val out: Out) {

    data class LoopingConfig(val loopCount: Int, val batchSize: Int)

    fun fibonacci(n: Long): Long {
        return when (n) {
            0L -> 0
            1L -> 1
            else -> fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
        }
    }

    class RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization(private val runnable: Runnable) : Runnable {
        private val idsOfThreadsUsed = mutableSetOf<String>()

        override fun run() {
            idsOfThreadsUsed.add(Thread.currentThread().id.toString())

            runImpl()
        }

        fun getThreadCount() = idsOfThreadsUsed.size

        fun runImpl() {
            runnable.run()
        }
    }

    /** Each threading case is expected to run, [[runnable]],
     *
     * [[LoopingConfig.loopCount]] number of times.
     *
     * However, it's up to each case how the runnable runs (on the same
     * or different thread in batches or not).
     * */
    abstract class ThreadingCase(
        val name: String,
        val loopingConfig: LoopingConfig,
        val runnable: RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization
    ) {
        abstract suspend fun go()
        fun getThreadsUsed(): Int {
            return runnable.getThreadCount()
        }
    }


    class CaseNoThreading(
        loopingConfig: LoopingConfig,
        runnable: RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization
    ) : ThreadingCase(
        "case1_noThreading",
        loopingConfig,
        runnable
    ) {
        override suspend fun go() {
            for (i in 0 until loopingConfig.loopCount) {
                runnable.run()
            }
        }
    }

    class CaseCoRoutineNoAsync(
        loopingConfig: LoopingConfig,
        runnable: RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization
    ) : ThreadingCase(
        "CoRoutine: no async{}",
        loopingConfig,
        runnable
    ) {
        override suspend fun go() {
            for (i in 0 until loopingConfig.loopCount) {
                coroutineScope {
                    runnable.run()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CaseThreadPool(
        loopingConfig: LoopingConfig,
        runnable: RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization
    ) : ThreadingCase(
        "ThreadPool: most vanilla",
        loopingConfig,
        runnable
    ) {
        val threadPool = ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())

        override suspend fun go() {
            for (i in 0 until loopingConfig.loopCount) {
                threadPool.execute(runnable)
            }

            waitForThreadPoolTasksToFinish()
        }

        private fun waitForThreadPoolTasksToFinish() {
            threadPool.shutdown()
            threadPool.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }
    }

    class CaseThreadPoolUsingFutures(
        loopingConfig: LoopingConfig,
        runnable: RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization
    ) : ThreadingCase(
        "ThreadPool-ForkJoinPool: with features",
        loopingConfig,
        runnable
    ) {
        val threadPool = ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())

        override suspend fun go() {
            val futures = mutableListOf<Future<*>>()

            for (i in 0 until loopingConfig.loopCount) {
                val future = threadPool.submit(runnable)
                futures.add(future)
            }

            futures.forEach { it.get() }
        }
    }

    class CaseThreadPoolUsingFuturesWithBatches(
        loopingConfig: LoopingConfig,
        runnable: RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization
    ) : ThreadingCase(
        "ThreadPool-ForkJoinPool: with features and batching",
        loopingConfig,
        runnable
    ) {
        val threadPool = ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())

        override suspend fun go() {
            val futures = mutableListOf<Future<*>>()

            for (i in 0 until (loopingConfig.loopCount / loopingConfig.batchSize)) {
                val future = threadPool.submit {
                    for (j in 0 until loopingConfig.batchSize) {
                        runnable.run()
                    }
                }
                futures.add(future)
            }

            futures.forEach { it.get() }
        }
    }

    class CaseCustomThreadPoolWithDoubleThreadsOfProcessors(
        loopingConfig: LoopingConfig,
        runnable: RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization
    ) : ThreadingCase(
        "ThreadPool-ForkJoinPool: with double threads of processors",
        loopingConfig,
        runnable
    ) {
        val threadPool = ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2)

        override suspend fun go() {
            for (i in 0 until loopingConfig.loopCount) {
                threadPool.execute(runnable)
            }

            waitForThreadPoolTasksToFinish()
        }

        private fun waitForThreadPoolTasksToFinish() {
            threadPool.shutdown()
            threadPool.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }
    }

    class CaseDefaultParallelStreams(
        loopingConfig: LoopingConfig,
        runnable: RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization
    ) : ThreadingCase(
        "ParallelStreams: default.",
        loopingConfig,
        runnable
    ) {
        override suspend fun go() {
            (0 until loopingConfig.loopCount).toList()
                .parallelStream()
                .forEach { runnable.run() }
        }
    }

    class CaseCoroutineWithAsync(
        loopingConfig: LoopingConfig,
        runnable: RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization
    ) : ThreadingCase(
        "CoRoutine: with async{}",
        loopingConfig,
        runnable
    ) {
        override suspend fun go() {
            coroutineScope {
                val tasks = List(loopingConfig.loopCount) {
                    async {
                        runnable.run()
                    }
                }

                tasks.forEach { it.await() }
            }
        }
    }


    class CaseCoroutineWithDispatcherIOAsync(
        loopingConfig: LoopingConfig,
        runnable: RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization
    ) : ThreadingCase(
        "CoRoutine: with async(Dispatchers.IO){}",
        loopingConfig,
        runnable
    ) {
        override suspend fun go() {
            coroutineScope {
                val tasks = List(loopingConfig.loopCount) {
                    async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        runnable.run()
                    }
                }

                tasks.forEach { it.await() }
            }
        }
    }


    class CaseCoroutineWithDispatcherIOAsyncAndBatching(
        loopingConfig: LoopingConfig,
        runnable: RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization
    ) : ThreadingCase(
        "CoRoutine: with async(Dispatchers.IO){} Batched",
        loopingConfig,
        runnable
    ) {
        override suspend fun go() {
            coroutineScope {
                val tasks = List(loopingConfig.loopCount / loopingConfig.batchSize) {
                    async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        for (j in 0 until loopingConfig.batchSize) {
                            runnable.run()
                        }
                    }
                }

                tasks.forEach { it.await() }
            }
        }
    }

    class NamedRunnable(val name: String, val runnable: Runnable) : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            runnable.run()
        }
    }

    data class RunConfig(
        val namedRunnable: NamedRunnable,
        val loopingConfig: LoopingConfig
    )

    private fun runBenchmark(runConfig: RunConfig) {
        val myRunnable = runConfig.namedRunnable
        val loopingConfig = runConfig.loopingConfig
        out.info("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        out.info("Starting benchmark of different threading options.")
        out.info("This run is configured with:")
        out.info("runnable type: ${myRunnable.name}")
        out.info("Loop count   : ${loopingConfig.loopCount}")
        out.info("Batch size   : ${loopingConfig.batchSize}")
        out.info("")

        val list = listOf(
            CaseNoThreading(
                loopingConfig = loopingConfig,
                RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization(myRunnable)
            ),
            CaseCoRoutineNoAsync(
                loopingConfig,
                RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization(myRunnable)
            ),
            CaseThreadPool(
                loopingConfig,
                RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization(myRunnable)
            ),
            CaseThreadPoolUsingFutures(
                loopingConfig,
                RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization(myRunnable)
            ),
            CaseThreadPoolUsingFuturesWithBatches(
                loopingConfig,
                RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization(myRunnable)
            ),
            CaseCustomThreadPoolWithDoubleThreadsOfProcessors(
                loopingConfig,
                RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization(myRunnable)
            ),
            CaseDefaultParallelStreams(
                loopingConfig,
                RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization(myRunnable)
            ),
            CaseCoroutineWithAsync(
                loopingConfig,
                RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization(myRunnable)
            ),
            CaseCoroutineWithDispatcherIOAsync(
                loopingConfig,
                RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization(myRunnable)
            ),
            CaseCoroutineWithDispatcherIOAsyncAndBatching(
                loopingConfig,
                RunnableRecordThreadsUtilization(myRunnable)
            )
        )

        list.forEach {
            val timeTaken = measureTimeMillis {
                runBlocking { it.go() }
            }

            val paddedCaseName = "${it.name}".padEnd(60, ' ')
            val millisTakenPadded = "$timeTaken ms".padEnd(8, ' ')
            out.info("$paddedCaseName took: $millisTakenPadded, and used: ${it.getThreadsUsed()} threads.")
        }
    }

    fun go() {

        out.info("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        out.info("Operating System name: ${System.getProperty("os.name")}")
        runBenchmark(
            RunConfig(
                NamedRunnable("Math.pow(3, 3) in a loop of 1000") {
                    for (i in 0 until 1000) {
                        Math.pow(3.0, 3.0)
                    }
                }, LoopingConfig(
                    loopCount = 100000,
                    batchSize = 100
                )
            )
        )

        runBenchmark(
            RunConfig(
                NamedRunnable("fibonacci(23)") {
                    fibonacci(23)
                }, LoopingConfig(
                    loopCount = 2000,
                    batchSize = 10
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] Operating System name: Mac OS X 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] Starting benchmark of different threading options. 
[INFO] This run is configured with: 
[INFO] runnable type: Math.pow(3, 3) in a loop of 1000 
[INFO] Loop count   : 100000 
[INFO] Batch size   : 100 
[INFO]  
[INFO] case1_noThreading                                            took: 2817 ms , and used: 1 threads. 
[INFO] CoRoutine: no async{}                                        took: 3446 ms , and used: 1 threads. 
[INFO] ThreadPool: most vanilla                                     took: 579 ms  , and used: 10 threads. 
[INFO] ThreadPool-ForkJoinPool: with features                       took: 559 ms  , and used: 10 threads. 
[INFO] ThreadPool-ForkJoinPool: with features and batching          took: 546 ms  , and used: 10 threads. 
[INFO] ThreadPool-ForkJoinPool: with double threads of processors   took: 555 ms  , and used: 20 threads. 
[INFO] ParallelStreams: default.                                    took: 571 ms  , and used: 10 threads. 
[INFO] CoRoutine: with async{}                                      took: 3582 ms , and used: 1 threads. 
[INFO] CoRoutine: with async(Dispatchers.IO){}                      took: 959 ms  , and used: 91 threads. 
[INFO] CoRoutine: with async(Dispatchers.IO){} Batched              took: 600 ms  , and used: 63 threads. 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] Starting benchmark of different threading options. 
[INFO] This run is configured with: 
[INFO] runnable type: fibonacci(23) 
[INFO] Loop count   : 2000 
[INFO] Batch size   : 10 
[INFO]  
[INFO] case1_noThreading                                            took: 288 ms  , and used: 1 threads. 
[INFO] CoRoutine: no async{}                                        took: 289 ms  , and used: 1 threads. 
[INFO] ThreadPool: most vanilla                                     took: 1497 ms , and used: 10 threads. 
[INFO] ThreadPool-ForkJoinPool: with features                       took: 1245 ms , and used: 10 threads. 
[INFO] ThreadPool-ForkJoinPool: with features and batching          took: 1033 ms , and used: 10 threads. 
[INFO] ThreadPool-ForkJoinPool: with double threads of processors   took: 1219 ms , and used: 20 threads. 
[INFO] ParallelStreams: default.                                    took: 1327 ms , and used: 10 threads. 
[INFO] CoRoutine: with async{}                                      took: 292 ms  , and used: 1 threads. 
[INFO] CoRoutine: with async(Dispatchers.IO){}                      took: 1439 ms , and used: 64 threads. 
[INFO] CoRoutine: with async(Dispatchers.IO){} Batched              took: 1666 ms , and used: 64 threads.
```

Comment: Why are you mixing coroutines with executors?  And code like this is often slower with threading, which can add significant overhead.

Comment: 1. Use proper tools like JMH or do a proper warmup manually (but really, use JMH). 2. Use the result of fibonacci somewhere, because otherwise JVM could entirely remove its code. 3. Read on how to write microbenchmarks for JVM as this is not trivial. 4. Keep your tests simple. With all your tooling and abstractions it is hard to be sure what is going on exactly. You may miss that you are doing something different than you think. Also, for readers in SO, it takes 5x more time to understand your tools than the benchmark itself.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I am not mixing them. I am comparing them.